# Files are missing after move

Tags: unix

I tried to move .html files into a subdirectory called 'html' and now I cannot find the files. Here is what I did (with the error message):

```
$ mkdir html
$ for FILE in $(ls *html) ; do mv $FILE .html ; done
mv: cannot stat 'html:': No such file or directory
$ cd html
$ ls *.html
ls: cannot access '*.html': No such file or directory
```

So my question: where have they disappeared?

Comment: @Ken Y-N and e7andy, thanks for noting the typo. So I found the file called '.html'. But I guess that all my presious .html files are gone now, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems; first, there is a typo:

```
mv $FILE .html
         ^
```

That `.` shouldn't be there! Second, your list of files will include the `html` directory itself, so to exclude it, try:

```
for FILE in *html ; do if ! [ -d "$FILE" ] ; then mv "$FILE" html ; fi ; done
```

Note that I use `*html` rather than `$(ls *html)` to avoid picking up the contents of the `html/` directory, then do the move as long as we don't have a directory name.

Comment: Thanks for noting the typo... Indeed I guess that one screwed everything up. But where to I find this dubious '.html

Comment: Before doing any of this kind of looping, I always test out with something like `then echo mv "$FILE" html` just to make sure I'm not doing anything too stupid.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. Indeed I screwed it up because I fogot the `.`

Answer (score 1):

You have effectively moved all *html files to a file named .html. Only the last *html file will be left since every move will overwrite the previous move.

Comment: The .html file is located in the same directory as where you ran the move command.
To list all files including those that starts with "." run: ls -la